# amChart and React js (version 15) (es6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, amcharts

I'm trying to integrate [amchartsjs](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/donut-chart/) into React js. Upon an npm installation (I can see the amcharts module in the node_modules), I don't know how I'll import it to my component (and ultimately use the pie chart from it).

Note: I haven't gotten it to work and idk how. If you know and want to work on a quick example (jsfiddle, codepen) to a simple pie chart. that'll be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official plugin for `React`. Docs: [amcharts3-react](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-react). [Demo app](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-react/tree/master/examples/webpack-export).